# Converting a Riemann sum to a definite integral.

Tags: calculus, riemann-integration

I was wondering what happens to the constant $\pi$ when we change from the riemansum,

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \dfrac{\pi}{n} \sin(\dfrac{{\pi}i}{n})$

to an integral form. My guess is that we end up with the integral

$\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin({\pi}x)$ and not $\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(x)dx$

My books disagrees while symbolab agrees so I'm rather confused. Anyone have any enlightenment?

Comment: I think it's $\int_{0}^{1} \sin({\pi}x)$ or $\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(x)$. Both are same.

Comment: @Hypernova The first if $2$ while the second is $\frac{2}{\pi}$.

Comment: I forgot $\pi$ in the first one sorry

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the following formula :

$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow+\infty} \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f\left(a+k \frac{b-a}{n}\right)=\int_a^b f(t) d t
$$

By choosing $a=0, b=\pi$, we get

$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow+\infty} \frac{\pi}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f\left(k \frac{\pi}{n}\right)=\int_0^\pi f(t) d t
$$

Then we choose $f(x)=\sin(x)$ :

$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow+\infty} \frac{\pi}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \sin\left(k \frac{\pi}{n}\right)=\int_0^\pi \sin(t) d t=2
$$

Note that $\int_0^\pi \sin(t) d t =\pi\int_0^1 \sin(\pi t) d t$, maybe that's what you found.